# docker -v option with only one field

Tags: docker

From the doc [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

> -v or --volume: Consists of three fields, separated by colon characters (:). The fields must be in the correct order, and the meaning of each field is not immediately obvious.

But I have seen someone using -v flag which only consists of one field:

```
docker run -v /data ubuntu
```

What does this option mean? Is this a bind mounts or volume type?

Comment: https://rominirani.com/docker-tutorial-series-part-7-data-volumes-93073a1b5b72
This article will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker support three type volume and the one above is anonymous volume

**anonymous volume**

> An anonymous volume is useful for when you would rather have Docker
>   handle where the files are stored. It can be difficult, however, to
>   refer to the same volume over time when it is an anonymous volumes. To
>   create an anonymous volume:

```
docker run -v /path/in/container ...
```

To find this volume you need to the following step to check the long ID of volumes.

```
docker inspect container_id
```

look into `Mounts` and then run

```
docker volume ls | grep volume_id
```

You will see the volume is created.

**host volume**

> A host volume lives on the Docker host's filesystem and can be
>   accessed from within the container. To create a host volume:

```
docker run -v /path/on/host:/path/in/container ...
```

**named volume**

> A named volume is similar to an anonymous volume. Docker manages where
>   on disk the volume is created, but you give it a volume name. To
>   create a named volume:

```
docker volume create somevolumename
docker run -v name:/path/in/container ...
```

[docker-different-types-of-volumes](https://success.docker.com/article/different-types-of-volumes)

Answer (score 0):

All three fields are not mandatory
"docker run -v /data ubuntu" creates a new volume mounted to /data in a ubuntu container.